# Using negation in disabled attribute of h:selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

Could someone please tell me how to use negation in the value of a component say checkbox to enable and disable it?

I have to disable a checkbox when the value of a property (somevalue) in bean is false.

like in

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="smthing" disabled="#{!somevalue}"></h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

For bean property

```
boolean somevalue;
```

should be diabled but it doesnt work. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Also could someone please clarify if no value is assigned to the boolean what will be the case then.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to reference it through the managed bean:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="#{!bean.somevalue}" />
```

Another way, which is in my humble opinion prettier to read, for sure if the boolean property has a self-documenting name (`somevalue` isn't), is using the `not` keyword:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="#{not bean.somevalue}" />
```

---

> *Also could someone please clarify if no value is assigned to the boolean what will be the case then.*

The `boolean` is a primitive and just defaults to `false` when uninitialized as instance variable. If you have used a `Boolean`, it would have defaulted to `null`.

Comment: How to add html data attribute in `h:selectBooleanCheckbox`?  That is `<input type="checkbox" data-checked="4" />`. Here `data-checked` is attribute to be added in JSF tag.

Comment: Hello i have similar structure, but disabled="#{bookingBean.viewDisabled}" is referring to public boolean isViewDisabled(). How is that possible?